# How to reverse all but the first and last element of an array without modifying an existing function?

Tags: c++, arrays

Just to be clear, I am not allowed to use any std function for this.
I wrote a function to reverse all contents of a double array. How can I make the function reverse all but the first and last element *without* modifying the function?

```
void reverse_array(double *arr, int size)
{
  double temp;
  for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < ((size - 1) - j); i++){
      temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
      arr[i + 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

with the function call

```
reverse_array(array + 1, size - 1)
```

I can reverse all but the first element. I would have thought the call would reverse all but the first *and* last element since the pointer moved one element down and the size dictates how often the values get swapped.

Comment: If the size of the entire array is `size`, then what is the size of the array without first and last element?

Comment: You have an off by one error.  If you want to exclude the first and last elements then the size of that sub array is `size - 2`

Comment: Clearly it should be `reverse_array(array + 1, size - 2)`. An array without the first and last elements is smaller by two.

Comment: Double loop to reverse an array ?! A simple loop does the job.

Comment: @jarod42 yea, and a one liner can do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just to avoid future downvotes, what was the problem with the question? I am still learning and this was my first try with the exercise so I dont think everything has to work efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function call

```
reverse(array + 1, size - 2);
```

When you reverse all but the first and last element, the section of the array given to `reverse` is two elements shorter, hence the `size - 2`

Answer (score 0):

If size is the array size then can you try size - 2 instead of - 1?